# Divergence-free field vanishing in boundary of a domain

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

Can you give me an example of a divergence-free field in a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ vanishing in the boundary $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Hint: See if you can write such a field on the unit ball. Then use that to write a vector field on the domain.

Comment: How about the function 1/r?

Comment: Its domain is R /{0}

Comment: You were, of course, right. I deleted my answer.